# Runtime error 91

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I'm receiving the error `Runtime 91 error` on the line `r = Bcell.Row`. How do I fix the error?

Trying to define a range to perform a few checks.

```
Dim LastRow, SECTYPE, Bcell, r As Range

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row()

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="X"

If LastRow > 1 Then
    Set SECTYPE = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
    For Each Bcell In SECTYPE
        r = Bcell.Row


        If Trim(Bcell.Value) = "CO" Or Trim(Bcell.Value) = "PO" Then
            If (Trim(Bcell.Offset(0, -1).Value) = "SWAPOPT") And UCase(Trim(ActiveSheet.Range("i" & r).Value)) = "X" Or UCase(Trim(ActiveSheet.Range("i" & r).Value)) = "" Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("J" & r).Value = "-"
                    ActiveSheet.Range("J" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If

        ElseIf Trim(Bcell.Value) = "FU" Then
            If (Trim(Bcell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = 1 And InStr(Trim(Bcell.Offset(0, -2).Value), "IB") <> 0) Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("J" & r).Value = "-"
                ActiveSheet.Range("J" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
           End If


        ElseIf Trim(Bcell.Value) = "OS" Then
            If (Trim(Bcell.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> "AUD") Then
                    ActiveSheet.Range("J" & r).Value = "-"
                    ActiveSheet.Range("J" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If

        End If
    Next Bcell
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Set` the variable like so:

```
Set r = Bcell.Row
```

Comment: Think that might just change the error from 91 (Object variable or With block variable not set) to 424 (Object required) `Bcell.Row` will return a `Long` - unlike `Bcell.EntireRow` which would return a `Range`. It looks like `r` is just used as the string representation of the row number so it should be declared as a `String` and then the `Set` would definitely not be needed. Even better would be to just use `Offset` consistently and then `r` wouldn't be needed at all